# Is Swami Vivekananda a Jivan Mukta according to the following?

Tags: scripture, vivekananda, ramakrishna

Is it true that Swami Vivekananda was a Jivan Mukta?

I am asking the answer from anyone of the three sources: words of Vivekananda, words of his guru RamaKrishna paramahamsa and (prophecy by) scriptures.

Comment: Please try to do comment in case of any issue with the question.

Comment: How it is an opinion based? I am clearly giving some sources and I am not asking in general.

Comment: I am not asking whether he is a Jivam Mukta or not.

Comment: You want to know whether according to his followers he was a Jivanmukta or not? Or whether his Guru said something like that or not?

Comment: @Rickross My intention is to know from any personality of at least Vivekananda's stature.

Comment: Ok I understood

Comment: Om NaMah Shantihi...

Comment: @hanugm he is considered self realized according to maha periyava(68th pointiff of kanchi kamakoti peetham)

Answer (score 3):

Swami Vivekananda (Narendra) was nitya siddha or ever free according to Sri Ramakrishna.

> Pointing to Narendra, the Master said: "You all see this boy. He
> behaves that way here. A naughty boy seems very gentle when with his
> father. But he is quite another person when he plays in the chandni.
> **Narendra and people of his type belong to the class of the ever-free.
> They are never entangled in the world. When they grow a little older
> they feel the awakening of inner consciousness and go directly toward
> God. They come to the world only to teach others. They never care for
> anything of the world. They are never attached to 'woman and gold'.**
>
> "The Vedas speak of the homa bird. It lives high up in the sky and
> there it lays its egg. As soon as the egg is laid it begins to fall;
> but it is so high up that it continues to fall for many days. As it
> falls it hatches, and the chick falls. As the chick falls its eyes
> open; it grows wings. As soon as its eyes open, it realizes that it is
> falling and will be dashed to pieces on touching the earth. Then it at
> once shoots up toward the mother bird high in the sky."

**The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna, Chapter 1, Master and Disciple**